# DataContext.ExecuteQuery(CustomType, Query) returns IEnumerable of initialized CustomType

Tags: c#, sql-server, ienumerable, datacontext

I need to execute runtime defined SQL queries on a database and show results on a datagrid.
I'm using this code to query the database. It should return an IEnumerable of runtime defined objects of customType

```
List<dynamic> result;
using (context = new DataContext(ConnStr))
{
   IEnumerable enumerable = context.ExecuteQuery(customType, query);
   result = enumerable.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
}
```

The sample customType and Query I'm using are as follows

CustomType: CustomType is created at runtime and it's equivalent to:

```
class customType 
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Query:

```
Select id from TestTable
```

What ExecuteQuery is returning a list of customType objects that id is 0 in all of them.
I did the same with context.ExecuteQuery and this time I defined my customType in compile time (<> operator does not work with Type instances), and it worked as expected and returned list of legit ids.
I checked msdn page and find this interesting description:

> Public method  *ExecuteQuery(String, Object[])*  Executes SQL
>   queries directly on the database **and returns objects**.
>
> Public method *ExecuteQuery(Type, String, Object[])*  Executes SQL queries directly on
>   the database.

Any help is appreciated.

Update:
TestTable definition in my SQL Server database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [BasePath] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

(if there's any syntax error it's a typo)

Comment: Please post the definition of `customType` and the SQL query.

Comment: And schema of you table.